# What could cause Safari to be choppy while scaling the browser?

Tags: drupal, safari, fluid

I have a Drupal 7 site with a fluid image grid (4x4). As the browser scales down, the images do as well so everything fits nicely.

This runs smoothly on my PCs in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari 5. On the several Macs I've tested, it runs well in Firefox and Chrome.

If I try to do this in Safari on a Mac, it is extremely choppy. However, Safari 5 on certain Macs seems to run just fine, but one was a bit choppy. Across the board, Safari 6 is not smooth at all.

So far I've tried getting rid of all my js files, and I've also compressed my css and js through Drupal's settings.

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After going though all javascript and css transitions, I couldn't find anything. We then switched the site from a cheap shared godaddy server to Rackspace cloudsites. Everything is smooth as can be.